# Cassandra trigger jar is loading but not executing the class

Tags: cassandra

I have created the custom trigger.jar and placed in the directory where Cassandra service can read the same, after performing the *"nodetool realoadtriggers"* it just prints "Loading new /trigger.jar" in system.log, but it's not executing the java class in the jar.

Note: Also, I have created the trigger on the table which should trigger this custom trigger jar on writing the inserting the data to the table, but it's not loading the class

The java class implements ITrigger overrides argument method. Any pointers for debugging the same will be helpful.

Cassandra verison - DSE 6.7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [DSE 6.0 upgrade guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgdDSE51to60.html):

> The `org.apache.cassandra.triggers.ITrigger` interface **was modified** from `augment` to `augmentNonBlocking` for non-blocking internal architecture. **Updated trigger implementations must be provided on upgraded nodes**.

So you need to change your implementation to comply.

Comment: Thanks, Alex, It was the DSE version that I didn't notice.
However, didn't found any lib/jar having interface org.apache.cassandra.triggers.ITrigger with augmentNonBlocking method defined in it.

Comment: As I understand, you need to pull `dse-db-<version>.jar` into your project to get access to that changed interface.  Although, in general triggers aren't recommended for DSE 6.x, as they may affect performance of the TPC-based architecture